# How to turn off the proxy settings on chrome browser through selenium webdriver?

Tags: java, selenium, proxy, selenium-chromedriver

When I navigate to my url on chrome, I get The system cannot find the file specified." . I thought it might be due to automatic proxy settings on chrome.
I want to explicitly turn off the proxy setting before starting chrome browser in selenium. I tried below, it isn't working. Can anyone help me

```
ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
DesiredCapabilities dc = DesiredCapabilities.chrome();
dc.setCapability("chrome.setProxyByServer", false);
System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver",sChromeDriverPath);
WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();
```

No errors are thrown at any point of time but URL doesn't open up

Tia
Anjana

Answer (score 3):

You need to pass the options object to the chrome driver when you initialize it. If you use a specific capability then pass it to the `chromeDriver()`, so that chrome knows what to start with. Also there is no JSON object as setProxyByServer in chrome, instead use `noProxy` JSON object. [Check this out.](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/selenium-users/38gUPQ6-yN4/Il6ewuI60RAJ) Here's how -

```
Proxy proxy=startProxy();
proxy.setProxyType(ProxyType.MANUAL); 
proxy.setNoProxy("");
ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
DesiredCapabilities dc = DesiredCapabilities.chrome();
dc.setCapability(CapabilityType.PROXY, proxy);
System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver",sChromeDriverPath);
dc.setCapability(ChromeOptions.CAPABILITY, options);
WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver(dc);
```

[More info about chrome capabilities](https://sites.google.com/a/chromium.org/chromedriver/capabilities). Hope it helps.

Comment: How silly? Didn't notice that actually. Thanks for pointing it out.But unfortunately problem is still not solved.

Comment: @Anjana thats because there is no `setProxyByServer` on chrome object as and its used for IE browser only. Instead use the `noProxy` JSON object available. Updated code with that.